# Override #pragma once with standard #ifndef MS-VC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I haven't seen any answers to this question (which probably means that it's not allowed) but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Is there any way to override the automatic generation of `#pragma once` in `.h` or `.hpp` files created using MS Visual-C++ to use the standard header guards of using portable friendly preprocessor directives?

```
#ifndef _V_DESCRIPTOR_ 
#define _V_DESCRIPTOR_
 // some code here
#endif
```

Comment: In my experience, `.cpp` files don't have include guards of any sort...  Also note that `#define __XYZ__` is not portable, that macro name is reserved!

Comment: My mistake, I meant .h files. I'll edit.

Comment: Your new example is still a reserved name.  Anything starting with double underscore, or underscore + capital letter, is reserved and should not be used by your code.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I have a header file that uses that exact convention (see Ogre3d framework tutorial) so... good to know that I shouldn't be doing that. I'll correct in edit.

Comment: I know, there are a LOT of tutorials that suggest this pattern.  Took me a while to break the bad habit.

Comment: All the major compilers support #pragma once and it "can" have advantages over header guards such as it doesn't create a define that may get accidentally reused elsewhere or misspelled.

Clang, GCC(as of version 3.4) and Microsoft VC++ support it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your real question, I don't think Visual Studio has any option for that, but it would be pretty simple to do with the Visual Studio Extensibility Toolkit, so I'm sure someone has written a macro you can download.  Look around Tools -> Extension Manager -> Online Gallery, there's a large catalog of free addins you can install.

For example, the [Zoom C++ Class Wizard](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e35dfd63-8023-450d-be21-d58be27def61?SRC=VSIDE) appears to generate both styles of include guard.  But I've never used it so I can't make a recommendation one way or the other.