# Visual Studio 2015 Header File Generation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-templates

Microsoft thinks it is helpful to add

```
 #pragma once
```

to the top of all header files it generates. <s>It does not seem to be a template</s>, how can this be disabled.

I don't care about overriding to have some other template or whatever in it's place. I just want a blank document when I ask for one. Every visual studio version I've installed and used before has done this automatically. My first use of VS 2015 is my first encounter with this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override #pragma once with standard #ifndef MS-VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566595/override-pragma-once-with-standard-ifndef-ms-vc)

Comment: It may be a duplicate, however the answer provided is a bit extreme. I spent some more time and found a simple solution and posted below.

Answer (score 1):

The .h and .cpp files both have a default template file they use when creating a new document.

The text in these documents will copy into the newly generated h and cpp files, respectively:

```
$InstallPath$\VC\vcprojectitems\hfile.h
```

and

```
$InstallPath$\VC\vcprojectitems\newc++file.cpp
```

Example file path I use: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojectitems